# Traveling to US - Do I need to step up / down for Macbook Pro (2016)

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I live in the U.K. and I have a Macbook Pro (2016) which I purchased in Dubai. The power adapter works fine in U.K. / Dubai / India.

I am traveling to USA next week.

Do I need to buy the adapter so that it can be used in the 2-pin USA wall sockets or do I also need to buy something in addition to that - say, a step up / step power adapter (My apologies, I am not sure of what it is called exactly... to transform the voltage as well?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the correct adapter for your power adapter as it will automatically handle the input voltage

Apple has a [World Travel Adapter Kit](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202114) that supplies adapters for different countries/regions.  What you will need is the the US/Japan adapter included in the kit that has "flat parallel blades with holes."

[image]